# How do I update the Toolbar Buttons

Tags: ios, swift, cosmicmind

I am using [this](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material) phenomenal framework and had difficulties updating buttons on the toolbar. I followed the sample code of the [NavigationDrawerController](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/tree/master/Material/Programmatic/NavigationDrawerController/NavigationDrawerController). So initially, the toolbar is populated with a menuButton on the left side and two other buttons on the right side:

```
// From AppToolbarController.swift
fileprivate func prepareToolbar() {
    toolbar.leftViews = [menuButton]
    toolbar.rightViews = [switchControl, moreButton]
}
```

Now, when I want to change the buttons in the toolbar from another ViewController, I (naive as I am) do the following:

```
// From RootViewController.swift
fileprivate func prepareToolbar() {
    guard let tc = toolbarController else {
        return
    }

    tc.toolbar.rightViews = [someOtherButton]
}
```

However, this has no effect and the buttons remain unchanged. This method only works for me when toolbar.rightViews was not set before.

What is the proper way to update the toolbar buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be that you are calling the update `Toolbar` (`prepareToolbar`) function from the `viewDidLoad` function. The issue will be that the `RootViewController` is not actually connected to the `toolbarController`. Try moving the `prepareToolbar` function to the `viewWillAppear` function of the view controller. If this does not help, can you show the code setup? All the best!

Code Sample:

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {
    fileprivate var remindersButton: IconButton!

    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = Color.white
    }

    open override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        prepareRemindersButton()
        prepareToolbar()
    }
}

extension RootViewController {
    fileprivate func prepareRemindersButton() {
        remindersButton = IconButton(image: Icon.cm.bell, tintColor: .white)
        remindersButton.pulseColor = .white
    }

    fileprivate func prepareToolbar() {
        guard let toolbar = toolbarController?.toolbar else {
            return
        }

        toolbar.title = "Material"
        toolbar.titleLabel.textColor = .white
        toolbar.titleLabel.textAlignment = .left

        toolbar.detail = "Build Beautiful Software"
        toolbar.detailLabel.textColor = .white
        toolbar.detailLabel.textAlignment = .left

        toolbar.rightViews = [remindersButton]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great support (and framework). I will try that as soon as I can!

Comment: It's a pleasure :) All the best!